# fail to capture random engine by value

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have this code that cannot be compiled by gcc 8, but I cannot understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

template<class... T>
void diagnose(T... x);

int main()
{
    auto d = normal_distribution<double>(0.0, 1.0);
    auto g = default_random_engine();
    cout << d(g) << endl;
    auto gen = [=](){
        //diagnose(d, g);
        return d(g);   // ******
    };
    cout << gen() << endl;
}
```

The error message says (pointing to the line marked by `*******`):

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const std::normal_distribution<double>) (const std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>&)
```

The code, however, works if I change the capture to be by reference.

If I uncomment the commented `//diagnose` line, the error message is like this (need also change `return d(g)` to `return 1.0`):

```
undefined reference to `void diagnose<std::normal_distribution<double>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned long, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul> >(std::normal_distribution<double>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned long, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul>)'
```

As you can see, in the capture-by-value case, the parameter `g` is a const reference. But the `const` does not appear in diagnosis.

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Comment: I realize that the `diagose`  function is not able to detect the cv qualifier. For it to report the cv qualifier correctly, we may need to use universal reference `T&&...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `d` by value `[=]` so copy of this object is created inside lambda, but body of lambda function is `const` so you cannot change object inside lambda body. `normal_distribution::operator()` member is not-const. In const members you can invoke only const methods for member objects. You can resolve it by adding mutable to lambda

```
 auto gen = [=]() mutable {
    //diagnose(d, g);
    return d(g);   // ******
};
```

or passing `d` by reference

```
 auto gen = [&](){
        //diagnose(d, g);
        return d(g);   // ******
    };
```

Comment: Good answer (+1) but I think _"body of lambda function is const"_ would be better expressed as _"the objects captured by copy are const in the lambda body"_

Comment: I meant that body of lamba is translated into `unnamedClass::operator () const {}` so it is const member method.